# HTML element with no footprint, but can be a container for another element

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, templating, backbone-views

Is there an HTML element, or an element that, when combined with the correct CSS style properties, has no footprint except that it can be used as a container for other elements?

It would almost be like a "marker" on the page marker where actual HTML that does stuff should be placed by jQuery.

Example of what it might look like:

```
<span id='the_view_container' style='display:dont-do-anything'></span>
```

The reason I ask is because I'm working with Backbonejs and when I have to add a view to the screen, I find that I either have to specify the element that the view should be pegged to when creating the view, which has its drawbacks:

```
theView = new TheView({
    el:    $('#the-view-container')
});
```

Or I have to insert the view inside an existing element, usually a div. This creates difficulties with templating:

```
theView = new TheView({});
$('#the-view-container').html(theView.el);
$('#the-view-container').addClass('theViewClass');  // <-- Shouldn't have to do this
```

Any input is appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: So if I understand correctly what you're asking, you want an HTML element that is sizeless (and has no affect on page rendering) until it's filled with content, and can be selected via CSS-style selectors?

Comment: @Nightfirecat - Yes, its merely there to point to the place on the page that the content inside of it should be placed. The page would look exactly the same if the element's beginning ans end tags were commented out.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow Then using an element with `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`would be what you're after.

Comment: @mariusnn - Would this not also hide the contents of the div when they were added?

Comment: @ChrisDutrow True, but were not your problem that you did want to control when they became visible to the user (not as the content were generated)?

Comment: @mariusnn - No, my problem was that I wanted to mark where a view should be inserted into the page without the marker itself having any affect on the page.

Comment: @ChrisDutrow Then your outlined aproach of a `div` or a `span` where you add the styling-class  when you fill it will be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off dynamically creating an element.

However, you can create a 'nothing' element like this:

```
<div id="nothing" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0"></div>
```

Then set the `style` when needed:

```
$('#nothing').css('');
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the View's template  cannot contain all of the CSS necessary. The program logic must include the top-level class.

Comment: Why not? Can you include a stylesheet and apply the CSS via a `class`?

Answer (score 1):

A DOM-element not attached to the document-flow should do the trick.
Try a `div`for instance:

```
var detachedDiv = $('<div/>');

theView = new TheView({
    el:    detachedDiv
});
```

Then when you want the view to be attached you would append it to `<body>` for instance:

```
$('body').append(detachedDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

(assuming your CSS has no abnormal resets,) Simply use an empty `<div>` with an ID attached to it.

```
<div id="backboneJScontent"></div>
```

Since divs by default have 0 height, they don't render any space in the document flow until they are given a height, border, margin, outline, or padding. (They have none of those by default)

Then, when you need to insert content to it, you can just insert it directly to that div, selecting it just with the ID.

```
$("#backboneJScontent");
```

Comment: When a div is given content it's is given space, so adding content to an empty div in the DOM-flow would give it size (unless styled to `display:none` | `jQuery .hide()`)

Comment: From what I understood, the asker just needs it to be sizeless until it's filled with content, which is the default behavior.